How are the expressions "rather than" and "instead of" classified?
I found an old post lamenting people's tendency to precede "rather than" with a comma. Here is the example they used:

"We decided to go to the grocery store[,] rather than a restaurant."

They said that "rather than a restaurant" is essential, and so the preceding comma is wrong.
This makes no sense to me.

First, "rather than a restaurant" does not appear essential. If we delete the "rather than" statement, "grocery store" remains just as clear and specific.
Even if we assume the statement refers back to a previous debate about going to a specific grocery store or a specific restaurant, the reader's understanding of which grocery store is being referred to (i.e., restrictive info) does not change:
if the reader is aware of the prior context, they will already know which grocery store is being referred to; they don't need a "rather than" phrase to reiterate the other option from the past debate.
If the reader is unaware of the prior context, the presence of the "rather than" phrase still does nothing to specify or narrow down exactly which grocery store the statement is referring to because the grocery store is not named in the "rather than" phrase.

Second, it seems to me that "Rather than" heads a contrasting or negative phrase---just like "not" often does to fulfill a similar function. Compare:

"We decided to go to the grocery store, not the restaurant."
"I decided to text, not call."
"I decided to text, rather than call."

I'm at my wit's end with the "rather than" and "instead of" compounds. Everyone says they are compound prepositions, but I can't seem to find a clear explanation for the comma rules that govern them or their typical grammatical class in a sentence.
Look, I agree that a comma before a "rather than" or "instead of" phrase(/clause) feels ugly and awkward. But I need a logical reason to remove it.

While writing this, another possibility came to mind.
Given:

"We decided to go to the grocery store, rather than a restaurant."

The comma before "rather than" could indeed be incorrect if we took "rather than a restaurant" to be an elliptical prepositional phrase behaving adverbially to give context to the main clause's verb, "decided."

Written in full: "We decided to go to the grocery store rather than [to go to] a restaurant.")

As an adverbial that follows the main clause, it would make sense for there to be no comma. And as an adverbial, I can also argue that it's not contrasting or negative (as "not" is) but instead describes the conditions (options) under which the main verb ("decided") occurred; if it's not a contrasting statement, that's another reason we wouldn't need a comma before "rather than."

Can you add the link to the old question you're referring to?

Many commas are optional, and this seems to be an example to me.

What's the question here? Are you looking for people to validate your opinion?

Hi Grant. Welcome to EL&U! Interesting data.

Grant, what is your exact question? You have made loads of very interesting observations, but your readers don't know what question you want answered. Are you asking whether the rathe than phrase is essential? Ae you asking what the grammatical analysis is of the rather than phrase in terms of its grammatical relations and phrasal category? Please let us know :-)

Here's the link to the old question for those would like to see it: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62681/using-a-comma-before-rather-than

I suppose I'm looking for either validation or criticism. What's your opinion on my analysis of the grammatical classification of "rather than"---correct or incorrect? Do you guys agree that the old comment's explanation (i.e., that there is no comma because the information is essential) is not the right reason?

I'd not use a comma in 'We gave it to Jill rather than John', but would use one in 'We gave it to the rather needy-looking homeless person that we met on the way back from the gym, rather than [to] the professional-looking collectors with the PA and the slick presentation who were out in force on the high street'.

"I Spent All Morning Taking Out a Comma and All Afternoon Putting It Back" Oscar Wilde.

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language argues that rather is an adverb primarily, and that rather than can be analyzed as a coordinator in some situations.

The primary sense of rather is [...] I’d rather resign than accept
such humiliation. Here it is an adverb with a comparative meaning:
approximately “more readily, in preference to”. There are also uses
where this meaning is largely or wholly lost – a change facilitated by
the fact that the morphological base rath· no longer occurs without
the ·er suffix. Like as well as, rather than may introduce a
constituent that is syntactically coordinate or subordinate. Compare:
i
a. In the end he [survives][rather than conquers].
b. The dilemma has [deepened][rather than been resolved].
c. Wisdom and folly are [moral][rather than intellectual]
categories.
ii [Rather than individual security] it is [the security of an
ideological group] that is basic.
In [i] rather than links finite VPs, past-participials, and
attributive adjectives, and it is plausible to suggest that it, like
as well as, has been reanalysed as a coordinator. The meaning of coordinative ‘X rather than Y’ is “X, not Y”. In [ii], however,
rather than cannot be a coordinator because of its position: there is no reason to postulate reanalysis here, and we take the first
bracketed phrase to be an adjunct, with the adverb rather as its
head. Note that such fronting of ‘rather than Y’ is not possible in
[i]. Compare [ia] in this respect with the clearly non-coordinative
They obeyed the order rather than suffer torture or death. Here the [bolded] constituents are not syntactically alike (the
first being finite, the second non-finite), and fronting is permitted:
Rather than suffer torture or death they obeyed the order. In this case, unlike [71], rather has its comparative “in preference to”
meaning.

As for preceding rather than with a comma or not, none of the examples above have a comma before rather than; however, searching in the Corpus of Contemporary American English for rather than, one gets 60224 total hits and of these 30262 are directly preceded by a comma. Confining the search just to news articles, the ratio holds - 6920 total with 3330 preceded by a comma.
Now, whatever reasoning is put forward as to why the comma shouldn't be there, we still have to deal with the fact that prestigious publications like The New York Times and The Washington Post seem to find it perfectly acceptable, which would suggest that, like most pet peeves about punctuation, the proscription of that comma really just reflects a particular person's preferences rather than a hard and fast rule about the language in general.
Do any one the following really look like they need that comma taken out?

Still, he said he saw no harm in using free credit monitoring - as
long as it covered all three bureaus and consumers realized that it
was a "reactive" service that notified them of activity in their
credit file after it occurred, rather than preventing it. (NYT 2019)
Like Biden, Hickenlooper is positioning himself as a pragmatic
problem-solver, rather than an ideologically pure progressive.
(Washington Post 2019)
Bey praised Mr. Tigerman's decision to present the Holocaust Museum in
a more industrial style, rather than in a more overtly positive tone.
(Chicago Sun-Times 2019)

If we follow CGEL's view and take it as a coordinator in these cases, then it would follow that the comma between the elements is mostly optional and would follow the general rules for commas in coordinations: longer elements more likely to be marked off by commas, shorter elements less likely, with heavy or light punctuation styles also playing a factor.
No comma looks perfectly acceptable in the following example, but I do detect a slight pause before the rather which could be marked by a comma.

So it takes particular tenacity to be an artist in either of them, and
it requires a preference for the integrity of the work rather than the
rewards. (Chicago Tribune 2017)



How are the expressions "rather than" and "instead of" classified?

They should not be classified as expressions.
Rather than comprises two quite separate words:
Rather adv. = in preference
than (conj.) introduces a comparative or contrastive.
and
instead = in + stead. stead = [a/the] place. Instead is thus a prepositional phrase that has fused and become an adverb.
of (prep.) - Of is followed by an NP of some sort and a prepositional phrase is created. The prepositional phrase is adverbial.
Edit to add
Commas are use to indicate a short pause - use one if the cadence of the words require it.

Note DW256's quoting recognised authorities, with references.
